# Plot a two dimensional array using a dictionary with pandas/python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I  want to make a simple XY-plot based on the data in a dictionary. My data looks like thit:

```
D = {'str1': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],'str2': [[8, 9, 
10, 11, 12], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]}
```

Is there a way to just plot, for example, the first dictionary form D. 
The command should be something like

```
plt.plot("str1")
```

Comment: `plt.plot(D['str1'][0],D['str1'][1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command would look like

```
plt.plot(*D["str1"])
```

i.e. you select the `"str1"` entry from the dictionary and unpack it to the `x` and `y` arguments of `plot`.